# mySQL select occurrences in two columns given third colum value

Tags: mysql

i have a table like this

```
Sender_id | Receiver_id | Topic
  456     |     123     |   1
  123     |     456     |   3
  123     |     456     |   2
  456     |     123     |   2
  123     |     789     |   1
  123     |     456     |   1
  123     |     789     |   4
  456     |     123     |   1
```

I want to know for every given Topic who are the speakers (can be both sender or receiver) involved in that conversation

> eg. for Topic 2, Mr. 123 and Mr. 456 are the only two speakers

The desired result would be to have just the values: 123, 456

```
Speakers |   Topic
  123    |     2
  456    |     2
```

this is my first attempt but i want ot merge the two resulting columns

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT sender_id 
    FROM [table] 
    WHERE topic = '2'
    AND sender_id !=0
    GROUP BY sender_id) a  
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT receiver_id 
    FROM [table]
    WHERE topic = '2'
    AND receiver_id !=0
    GROUP BY receiver_id) b 
ON sender_id
```

Comment: The desired result would be to have just the values: 123, 456. mayeb i'm overhitnking..

Comment: isn't involved GROUPING? and maybe JOIN because you need to intersect the occurrence of senders and receivers in order not to have dulictes

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `JOIN`, you need a [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html):

```
SELECT sender_id Speakers
    FROM [table] 
    WHERE topic = '2'
    AND sender_id !=0
UNION
SELECT receiver_id 
    FROM [table] 
    WHERE topic = '2'
    AND receiver_id !=0
```

You don't need to group to remove duplicate values as the UNION does that for you.

Comment: '2' is probably an integer

Comment: how come a union and not JOIN? isnt necessary an intersectiona nd not an union?

Comment: No, a JOIN/intersection takes two sets (_A_,_B_) and merges the data where _A_ **AND** _B_ satisfy a condition. This gives you a set with data from both sides, e.g. to get the speaker and topic name for a topic, you can `JOIN` `topic` to `speaker` on a condition of topic id being 2 (`where topic = 2`), giving you TopicName from _A_ and SpeakerId from _B_. In your case, you are looking at two sets of ids and applying the same condition to both in _isolation_ to create a set containing items that are members of _A_ **OR** _B_, or both. This is a UNION - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Sender_id as speakers, Topic from Table1 WHERE Topic ='2'

UNION

SELECT Receiver_id as speakers, Topic FROM Table1 WHERE Topic = '2'
```

Working fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4cf5e3/2

Comment: what if i want to exclude myself from the speakers and say my id is 123?

Comment: @Francesco just add a condition to the speaker part  - `WHERE Topic = '2' AND Sender_id <> 123`

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,Sender_id INT NOT NULL
,Receiver_id INT NOT NULL
,Topic INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (sender_id,receiver_id,topic) VALUES
(456,123,1),
(123,456,3),
(123,456,2),
(456,123,2),
(123,789,1),
(123,456,1),
(123,789,4),
(456,123,1);

SELECT speaker FROM
(
SELECT sender_id speaker,topic FROM my_table
UNION
SELECT receiver_id,topic FROM my_table
) x
WHERE topic = 2;
+---------+
| speaker |
+---------+
|     123 |
|     456 |
+---------+
```